# group lines with a tag

Tags: awk, set

Each written line belongs to the first tag upward. 
For instance: ' The trucker is drunk ' belongs to AN8. I want to group all written lines belonging to the corresponding tag. Lines should remain in the same order.

input:

```
AN9
the cow is eating way too much
AN8
The trucker is drunk
AN9
The field are running out of herbs.
AN8
the truck is not going that staight
well of course the road is in curve
AN9
and
another line
AN8
The cop needs to check this out
AN9
now the cow is soooo big dude !
```

output:

```
AN9
the cow is eating way too much
The field are running out of herbs.
and
another line
now the cow is soooo big dude !
AN8
The trucker is drunk
the truck is not going that staight
well of course the road is in curve
The cop needs to check this out
```

Comment: sounds interesting, please add what you have tried so far and we gladly help!

Comment: Can a non-tag line start with "AN", e.g. `ANy chance this could happen?`. How about AN then a number e.g. `AN627 is tramadol 50mg.`. If all of the above - how can we identify a tag line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk '/^AN/ {id=$0;next} {a[id]=a[id]"\n"$0} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
AN8
The trucker is drunk
the truck is not going that staight
well of course the road is in curve
The cop needs to check this out
AN9
the cow is eating way too much
The field are running out of herbs.
and
another line
now the cow is soooo big dude !
```

If line starts with `AN`, use the info in the line as `ID` for array `a`.
Then store all lines in array `a`.  Finally print all data in array `a`

Comment: It works just fine but what if we have, let's say, ANx, BQx, ZOx, ... ? Shall I enumerate all the tags ?

Comment: You can use `/^...$/`.  If line is three characters, then set it as tag. Or `/^[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:digit:]]+/`.  You just need to fined some unique that hits only on the ID